# SetState in React ES6

Tags: reactjs, es6-class

I'm just learning React & I just can't seem to get setstate in the componentdidmount function to work. It would be adorable if you could help me out. I already tried to bind it.

I keep getting errors such as Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

```js
class ShareEvent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {copied: false};

  this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

 componentDidMount() {
  var clipboard = new Clipboard('#copy-button');
        clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
          this.setState({copied: true});
          e.clearSelection();
        });
        clipboard.on('error', function (e) {
          document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = 'Please copy manually.';
        });
  }

 handleChange(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.select();
  }

 render() {
  const EventURL = GenerateEventUrl(this.props.EventName,this.props.EventTimeUTC);
  return (
   <div>
        <h1>{this.state.copied ? "Copied!" : "Nicely done." }</h1>
        <p>Now, simply share the link below.<br />It will display{' '}
          <a href={EventURL}>the event</a>{' '}
          in the local time of whoever visits it.</p>
        <form>
          <div className="input-group">
            <input onClick={this.handleChange} type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={EventURL} readOnly id="copy-input" />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
              <button className="btn btn-default" type="button" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#copy-input" title="Copy to Clipboard">
                Copy
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `this` that references your component to your function. Change

```
function (e) {
    this.setState({copied: true});
    e.clearSelection();
}
```

to

```
function (e) {
    this.setState({copied: true});
    e.clearSelection();
}.bind(this)
```

or use ES6 arrow functions, which automatically bind `this`

```
e => {
    this.setState({copied: true});
    e.clearSelection();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. <3